# Tags of the week! April 1-7, 2019: Poetry & Non-Fiction — RESULTS

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

## WEEK: April 1-7, 2019
TAGS: [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) and [non-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-fiction)

---

## Results

Our first tag promo week got us off to a great start.  7 new questions from 4 users.

**And our winner is... April.**

Congrats.  April posted 4 questions, 3 for [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) and 1 for [non-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-fiction)

A special prize goes to NofP who achieved the difficult task of asking a question with both tags.

Honorable mentions to Linksassin for a question about [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) and Monica Cellio for a question about [non-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-fiction)

---

As a followup to our [fantastic tag contest](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1917/announcing-our-contest-results?cb=1), and to suggestions that we [continue the fun](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/suggestion-continue-question-pushes/1955) in a more informal way, here is Writing.SE's first:

## TAGS OF THE WEEK PROMO

### Rules:

- The contest runs for one week (or almost a week, in this case), Monday 12:01am to Sunday midnight. The day ends when StackExchange says it does.
- Post a new question using one or both of the tags of the week.
- Update the answer to this post with your name, tag(s), and a link to the question.
- You get one point for every question that, at the end of the week, is open, has one or more votes, and is correctly tagged.

### Prizes:

- One beautiful sack of bragging rights!
- Two sacks if you use both tags in the same question.

---

**Notes:**

- The contest started Monday?  But it's Tuesday (Wednesday for some people)!  Shush, it's the first week.
- Can we use questions we've already posted that are within this week's boundaries?  Yes.
- The goal is to increase questions on tags that have not yet reached the magic 200 questions.  My personal focus is tags that are in the top 40 tags but under 200 questions.
- Others may take over other weeks and they may have different goals.
- Each week we'll have two tags to choose from; the tags are deliberately different from each other.

Comment: The temptation is irresistible: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5017291/

Comment: @NofP Ha ha ha ha ha ha.

Comment: dedicated to all of you who do a great work in keeping this great site alive :)

Comment: Since this is featured and shows up in the Community Bulletin, maybe work the featured tags into the title for even more visibility?  I know people can just click the link, but that visual reminder on every page may help out.  I think worldbuilding did something similar when they ran topic challenges?

Comment: @Troyen Okay.  Done.

Comment: @Cyn wait, you picked these tags and I don't yet see an entry from you?  You've got a few hours left... :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Darn, I was hoping no one would notice.  I have been wracking my brains all week.

Comment: @MonicaCellio and others.  Does someone want to do next week's?  Or should I?  Starts in an hour and a half.

Comment: @Cyn go for it!  And you can pick something you have questions about this time. :-)

Comment: Well I thought I would have questions...

Answer (score 3):

## Entries

Add entries to this list in the following format:

Username, tag, link to question

One entry per question, not one entry per tag.

---

[Linksassin](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/33442/linksassin) (1)

- [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) [How can I incorporate poetry techniques to improve my prose?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/44304/33442)

[April](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/36670/april) (4)

- [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) 
  [Is there a "writer's room" for poetry?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44327/is-there-a-writers-room-for-poetry)
- [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) [Poetry when unstructured?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44326/poetry-when-unstructured)
- [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) [Publishing Poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44328/publishing-poetry/44329)
- [non-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-fiction) [Plain language with long required phrases](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44362/plain-language-with-long-required-phrases)

[NofP](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28528/nofp) (1)

- [non-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-fiction)[poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) [Making science for toddlers easy to remember](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44339/making-science-for-toddlers-easy-to-remember)

[Monica Cellio](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/1993/monica-cellio) (1)

- [non-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-fiction) [When blogging recipes, how can I support both readers who want the narrative/journey and ones who want the printer-friendly recipe?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/when-blogging-recipes-how-can-i-support-both-readers-who-want-the-narrative-jou)